# Implement a process builder which invoke apex on professional organization

Tags: apex, workflow, process-builder, invocable-method

How can I create a process builder which will invoke an apex method which is in a managed packaged from a Professional Edition Organization? 
When creating the Action, I can't find apex in the option whereas in other organization I am able to see it.

I did try creating the process builder on the managed package and installation can't proceed on the professional edition org.

Answer (score 1):

Unless/until you complete the Security Review, you can't install Apex Code in a Professional Edition. Professional Edition doesn't get Apex Code, so you can't link the Process Builder to Apex Code. Once you've passed your Security Review, you should be able to install your package's code in a Professional Edition org.